# Kendo MVVM in iOS UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, mvvm, kendo-ui, uiwebview

We have some custom HTML page embedded in an iOS UIWebView. We load the page with the path and then, all the scripts are loaded in the page and everything seems fine. Everything but one : the "enabled" state of the buttons. While it works 100% in Chrome and in Safari, once embedded in the UIWebView, it doesn't seems to be refreshed every time the button get pushed. But I click in a field, then the binding function seems to get called. I used the "enabled" binding as specified in [Kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/enabled).

*Working [sample here](https://jsbin.com/wafocup/8). If you load it with Safari on iPad you'll see the problem

Here is my HTML SAMPLE :

```
<div class="gui-header-section k-content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="recolteInfoDiagnostic">
        <div id="section1" data-bind="visible: isSectionVisible(1)">
            <div class="gui-form-section k-content">
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <ul class="fieldlist">
                            <li>
                                <label for="fname">First name</label>
                                <input id="fname" data-bind="value: firstNameSousc" class="k-textbox" /></li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                                <input id="lname" data-bind="value: lastNameSousc" class="k-textbox" /></li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Gender:</label>
                                <select id="cbxGenderSousc" data-bind="source: gendersDataSource, value: genderSousc"></select></li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="agree">License Agreement</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="agree" data-bind="checked: agreed" />
                                I have read the licence agreement</li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="gui-form-section k-content">
                <div>
                    <!-- Some content, ommited for clarity -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="section2" data-bind="visible: isSectionVisible(2)">
            <div class="gui-form-section k-content">
                <!-- Some content, ommited for clarity -->
            </div>

            <div class="gui-form-section k-content">
                <!-- Some content, ommited for clarity -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navToolBar" class="gui-header-section k-content">
            <div>
                <button data-bind="enabled: isBackEnabled, click: back" class="k-button k-primary">Back</button>
                <button data-bind="enabled: isNextEnabled, click: next" class="k-button k-primary">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And the javascript that goes with it :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var kendoViewModel = kendo.observable({
    formID: "informationsDiagnostic",
    visibleSectionNo: 1,
    totalPageNumber: 2,
    firstNameSousc: "",
    lastNameSousc: "",
    genderSousc: "",
    agreed: false,

    gendersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
            { text: "Male", lang: "en", value: "M" },
            { text: "Female", lang: "en", value: "F" }
        ]
    }),

    isBackEnabled: function() {
        return !(this.get("visibleSectionNo") === 1);
    },

    isNextEnabled: function() {
        return !(this.get("visibleSectionNo") === this.get("totalPageNumber"));
    },

    next: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.set("visibleSectionNo", this.get("visibleSectionNo") + 1);
    },

    back: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.set("visibleSectionNo", this.get("visibleSectionNo") - 1);
    },

    isSectionVisible: function(pageNumber) {
        return (pageNumber === this.get("visibleSectionNo"));
    }
});

$("#cbxGenderSousc").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: gendersDataSource,
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataTextField: "text"
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

kendo.bind($("#recolteInfoDiagnostic"), kendoViewModel);
```

});

Note that the data-bind on "visible" property works fine, but I just can't make it work correctly on the "enabled" property. All other bindings in the form are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out all you have to do is get rid of the "k-primary" style in the button tag.